# Display user most frequent menus in page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website that it has more than 50 menu items. I want to add a functionality to the website by which, users be able to choose his/her most frequent menu items and add them on the right side of the main page. It can help the user to find links easily.

How can I do this or what's your suggestion to accomplish this in the best way?

Thanks

Comment: how many menu items users can choose at most?

Comment: In my plan it's 5 menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion over this, is Create New SQL table, with Column `UserID`, and `FavMenuItemID`.

```
Create Table userFavMenuItem(
UserID INT,
FavMenuItemID INT
)
```

Do not forget to add foreign key constraints for both these columns.

So once user choose any Menuitem as Favorite, add a new row and when user want to delete any menu item, delete from this table based on `UserID`, and `FavMenuItemID`.

Now, to show Current Favorite menu items on right hand side, Just Get Favorite Menu itmes from this table using `UserID`.

**EDIT**

You have to create new page, where user can choose their Fav Menu Item(add/Delete), and also change their previous Fav selection also (at most user can have 5 Fav menu items), and also restrict user to choose only 5

Comment: Tnx. what's your idea about the way that how a user select menus? I mean the solution for selecting menus.

Comment: tnx for your answer. I'll use your solution.

Comment: What's your idea about creating a user control that users can drag & drop links on it and saving them in such as cookies or something like that? I know it's raw idea, but I like to do this task in different way. @Piyush

Comment: where you want to store user selection, in DB or cookies? Once user select their menu items, you have to store some where. if user selection is permanent then store in DB otherwise user can delete cookies also. you can store in Cookies also. User can also delete cookies. Create User control where user can drag & drop the menu he wants, and also change that, but overall concept is the same, however, you can choose any different way to implement that